# Architecture design dilemma. What's the best design?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out what's the best design I can go with for the following problem. I have a client on my phone that makes a connection to the internet. When there is an exception in the connection I want to display an informative popup to the user.

I have a class that queries the phone to see if there is a SIM card installed, the signal level, if phone is connected to wifi, the signal strength on the wifi, and if the settings are configured correctly.

I want to encapsulate this class as that's all it should do, just query the phone for various statuses. Should I returned a byte that packs various flags and let the caller figure out what to do with those flags? Should I tell the caller what type of error message to display? Should I have a flag for each status and have getters for them? Or is there a better design you can think of?

Comment: Keep your code [DRY](http://www.solidsyntaxprogrammer.com/dont-repeat-yourself/). you may want to consider splitting up that functionality into a few classes, since your one-class model looks like it's going to get out of hand quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is anything you can have the program do you should do.  What that means for this design is that your statuses will need to be mapped to an enum like the following:

```
  enum Statuses  
    {  
        NO_CONNECTION("no connection", NO_WIFI("no wifi"),
        ALL_GOOD("Everything is fine")  ;  //etc
    }
```

Your `Phone` class will want to look something like this:

```
class Phone  
{  
   Statuses currentStatus;  
   Signal currentWifiSignal;
   Signal currentRadioSignal;  
   boolean isSimInserted;   
}
```

The `Signal` class will hold the logic for determining a `Phone` connection strength and other attributes (none of which I am positive of).

During usage you will query the `Phone` object and in the event of an exception you will return to the invoker a `Phone` object that reflects the current state which in turn will allow a simple invocation on a `getter` to validate the current condition.